# Leaflet custom url \ custom tiles

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, tiles

I am working on a custom map with leaflet. So far everything worked fine, but unfortunately the program I am using to split my image into tiles dont start the count with 0 but instead with 1, so my tiles start with "1_1.jpg" and so my whole map is shifted by one tile on y- and x-axis. To rename the tiles is not an option, cuz there to many, so I was looking for a possibility to change the {x} and {y} value in

```
L.tileLayer('images/map/{z}/C{x}_R{y}.jpg',
```

to something like `x=x+1` and `y=y+1`, that would be my logic.
I've read that it would be possible with `getTileUrl` but I didn't understand how. I am still quite new to Javascript and this problem starts to drive me mad!

If anyone can help I would be very thankful.

Tile names are like "Cx_Ry.jpg" (for example first image "C1_R1.jpg") And here is the code.

```
var w = 16384, h = 16384; //Größe innerhalb Box

var map = L.map('image-map', {
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 5,
        crs: L.CRS.Simple,
        attributionControl: false,
}).setView([0, 0], 0);

var southWest = map.unproject([0, h], map.getMaxZoom());
var northEast = map.unproject([w, 0], map.getMaxZoom());
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

map.setMaxBounds(bounds);

L.tileLayer('images/map/{z}/C{x}_R{y}.jpg', {
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 5,
    tms: false,
    continuousWorld: 'false',
    noWrap: false,
    defaultRadius:1,
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend Leaflet's `TileLayer` class to provide your own `getTileUrl` method: http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html.

In this case, it would probably look something like this:

```
L.TileLayer.MyCustomLayer = L.TileLayer.extend({
    getTileUrl: function(coords) {
        // increment our x/y coords by 1 so they match our tile naming scheme
        coords.x = coords.x + 1;
        coords.y = coords.y + 1;

        // pass the new coords on through the original getTileUrl
        // see http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html 
        // for calling parent methods
        return L.TileLayer.prototype.getTileUrl.call(this, coords);
    }
});

// static factory as recommended by http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#class
L.tileLayer.myCustomLayer = function(templateUrl, options) {
    return new L.TileLayer.MyCustomLayer(templateUrl, options);
}

// create the layer and add it to the map
L.tileLayer.myCustomLayer('images/map/{z}/C{x}_R{y}.jpg', {
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 5,
    tms: false,
    continuousWorld: 'false',
    noWrap: false,
    defaultRadius:1,
}).addTo(map);
```

Code is untested, but should get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much, that surely goes in the right direction of what I want, unfortunately all what happens is that my map now completely disapears and I have no idea why :/

Comment: Any errors in console? If you look at the network tab, is it requesting the correct tiles?

Comment: Not that I would have noticed....but actually you can take a look at the whole thing here: http://orboroth.bplaced.net/karte.html this is the map with the code you gave me, if you switch to english on the top right on the navigation you can see the map without the code as it was before with wrong tile numbers.

Comment: Oh, I see what the problem is - we need to pass the template URL and options through in the constructor. I've updated the code in my answer to show this. The change is the `templateUrl` and `options` arguments to `L.tileLayer.myCustomLayer`, as well as passing them through to the constructor.

Comment: YES it worked :D I cant say how happy I am right now :D Thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Note that for reasons only know to the dev, you can't override `z` this way, and you need to instead implement your own `_getZoomForUrl()` if you also want to customize the scale parameter (search for `getTileURL` in https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/main/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js to see what else to override if you need custom values for "not just x and y")

Comment: (or abuse the system and just build a custom URL suffix and put that in `x`, then make the URL only use `{x}` at the end, of course. Leaflet doesn't care what's in `x`, it just puts it wherever it sees `{x}`)